# Questions relating to fixed issues?

Tags: discussion

Occasionally we have questions that relate to issues in the Salesforce Platform - for example, [JSON serialize is not handling aggregate results properly in Spring 13](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7493/json-serialize-is-not-handling-aggregate-results-properly-in-spring-13). When these are subsequently fixed, the question becomes moot.

So - what should we do? I *think* the answer is to close the question, since any further discussion/answer is unproductive. I wouldn't go so far as to delete, though, since it seems useful to have a record of regressions, in case a similar issue pops up again.

Thoughts?

---

I think then, the consensus is to leave them as-is with a prominent 'Fixed in Season 'YY' message, resorting to protection if necessary. Thanks, folks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm hesitant to say that we should close questions as you typically do that when it wasn't a good question to ask in the first place and there may be tooling and assumptions built into the system around that. I.E. shows up on moderator lists, users with many closed questions get flagged somehow, etc.

Also, if there is a regression and this bug appears again I would much rather someone edit the question and add a new answer/edit the existing answer than create a new question.

what can you do with a [closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question):

> When a question is closed, no additional answers may be posted to it, although the question and existing answers can still be edited (**by users with edit privileges**) and voted upon, and will continue to count for badges. The asker of a closed question may still accept an answer.

As an alternative I would recommend prominently updating the question and answer that this was fixed as I did [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/why-does-json-serialization-give-different-results-when-the-sobject-is-created-f).

If we do decide to close questions we should create a new close reason as none of the existing ones are a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say close, especially if answer was accepted (I'm not sure if you can still accept in a closed question). Or at least [protect](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/protect-questions)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd vote for editing prominently with a note when/how it was permanently fixed, and then closing it for discussion if it is unequivocally wrong for any further answers to be posted to it.

Answer (score 1):

I would vote for leaving these questions open. There doesn't seem to be an issue with people spamming these types of questions, so why would we need to close them? As a precaution, it may be a good idea to [protect](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/protect-questions) them as @eyescream suggested. I am just hesitant to close things when you never know what could come up with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be hard press to come up with a negative effect from these questions.  The only issue it seems would be the question implies the bug is still an issue, which would be best addressed by community edits with the "Fixed in Release XX" as Metadata suggestions in the question.

Feels like we're worrying about taking action on an issue that doesn't really exist.